# Call an object in a list with name

Tags: python, object, indexing

I need to know if there is a way to use a name for as an index for each member of an object list as in dictionaries.

```
import numpy as np

class Marker(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name: str
        self.location: np.ndarray

locations = np.random.rand(5,3)
names = ['apple','body','wear','orange','bear']

markers= []
for n,l in zip(names, locations):
    marker = Marker()
    marker.name = n
    marker.location = l
    markers.append(marker)
```

For example, in the above list is there a way to call objects in list with their names? like `markers['apple']` instead of `markers[0]`?

Comment: Use a `dict` instead of a list…? `markers[n] = marker`

Comment: What if two markers have the same name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if an object exists in a list, you can do so using the `in` operator:

```py
if marker in markers:
    # do stuff here
```

it seems you want to store a key-value pair of a `name` being a lookup for a `marker`. You could instead make `markers` a dictionary:

```py
markers= {}
for n,l in zip(names, locations):
    marker = Marker()
    marker.name = n
    marker.location = l
    markers[n] =marker
```

Then to access a given marker, do a lookup based on the name:

```py
marker = markers['apple']
```

If the only 2 data points being stroed in your `Marker` class, maybe drop the `Marker` object altogether and just store the `location` in the dict instead:

```py
markers['apple'] = location
```